# prevent direct access to AWS load balancer URL when using custom domain in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an AWS application load balancer set up to access a target group in an ECS Fargate. I have a custom domain `example.com` with an AWS-managed certificate with an alias targeting the load balancer. Thus if I enter `https://example.com/`, it hits the load balancer which forwards to my ECS Fargate container. It seems to work fine.

However if I go into the AWS console for the load balancer, I see a DNS name in the form `foo-bar-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com`. It turns out that I can bypass the `example.com` and access the load balancer directly (ignoring the certificate warning) using `https://foo-bar-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com`.

How can I easily prevent someone from directly accessing the load balancer by its AWS DNS name, bypassing the domain name in the hosted zone I've set up with the SSL certificate?

Surely this is a common scenario. I wouldn't be surprised if many setups in the wild did not address this detail, and have their load balancers directly exposed via the AWS DNS name. However I don't feel this configuration is ideal nor desirable. Note that how likely or easily someone could discover the load balancer DNS name is a separate issue and is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly handled on the backend, by returning a redirect if the host name doesn't match whatever host name your server is configured to respond to.

However with Application Load Balancers you can also configure a rule to handle this. The rule would specify that if the Host-header is `foo-bar-1234567890.region.elb.amazonaws.com` then 301 redirect to your preferred domain name.

Comment: I assume that CloudFormation [`AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html) is what you're referring to? Do you know of any example CloudFormation templates using this scenario, just to save a few hours of researching and experimenting?

Comment: If you are using CloudFormation, then yes, that's what I'm referring to. You didn't mention anything in your question about using CloudFormation.

Comment: I would accept examples in other formats, too, such as Terraform, because I'm sure they would refer to the same entities in AWS, and it would be less trouble to translate them that create them completely from scratch after reading the docs and experimenting.

Comment: I referred to CloudFormation `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule` because that was an easy way to refer to the entity that would be created in AWS. I would imagine that if you create this thing using Terraform, CloudFormation, the CLI, the console, or whatever, they will all results in some `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule` entity being created on AWS. However you want to document it, I can probably figure it out. In other words, I was requesting some more specific technical description of the what you described in prose. If you have it available, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Here's an official blog post on the feature: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/ I don't have a CloudFormation or Terraform example handy.

Comment: I think the blog post will be super-helpful, thanks!

Comment: Mark B, this works well, thanks. I added a separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75706423) with a more technically detailed example of exactly what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I went with Marc B's suggestion of adding an Application Load Balancer rule to restrict the `Host` header to match that of the expected domain (the one I have the SSL certificate for).

Rather than redirecting, I indicate the request is forbidden. Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS is a user convenience; the user might have intended HTTPS but inadvertently left off the `https:` in the URL; and redirecting is helping them out. But no user accidentally discovers the load balancer URL and inadvertently tries to connect to it. Thus I forbid direct access to the load balancer URL altogether.

I could approach this two ways: I could deny access if the load balancer URL is used, or I could *only* allow access if the correct domain is used (denying all others). The latter seems safer. (Maybe there is some additional third URL I don't know about; this would prevent that as well.)

Unfortunately [AWS application load balancer listener rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html) don't seem to accept `NOT` Boolean logic, so I can't easily override the default forwarding to the target group if the domain is not correct. So I take the opposite approach: I forbid all connections by default, and add an override rule to only allow connections if the domain is correct. Here's an example in CloudFormation. (Note that the SSL certificate and domain name are defined elsewhere.)

```yaml
  LoadBalancerListenerHttps:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !Ref DomainCertificateArn
      DefaultActions: 
        - Type: fixed-response
          FixedResponseConfig:
            StatusCode: 403
            ContentType: text/plain
            MessageBody: "Unsupported host domain name."

  LoadBalancerListenerHttpsRequireHostDomain:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      ListenerArn: !Ref LoadBalancerListenerHttps
      Priority: 1
      Conditions:
        - Field: host-header
          HostHeaderConfig:
            Values: !Ref DomainName
      Actions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
```

(You'll see lots of encouragement to use Terraform instead of CloudFormation, and I don't doubt it is more powerful. But it is my understanding that the IaC framework is still limited by the capabilities of the cloud platform. In this case, for example, I highly doubt that Terraform would somehow add support for a `NOT` condition in load balancer rules, because AWS itself does not support that. In theory a complex rules engine might allow it and then transform it to a default forbid with an override as I have done here, but don't imagine Terraform does this. In other words, in Terraform I would guess that you would be stuck with the same sort of configuration I've shown here. If my assumption is incorrect please let me know.)

I could allow the HTTP listener to continue indiscriminately redirecting to the HTTPS port, which eventually would provide the same HTTP Forbidden response if the domain were incorrect. But I prefer to take the same approach as above even with HTTP, to deny access to an incorrect domain even before redirection takes place.

```yaml
  LoadBalancerListenerHttp:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties: 
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      DefaultActions: 
        - Type: fixed-response
          FixedResponseConfig:
            StatusCode: 403
            ContentType: text/plain
            MessageBody: "Unsupported host domain name."

  LoadBalancerListenerHttpRequireHostDomain:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      ListenerArn: !Ref LoadBalancerListenerHttp
      Priority: 1
      Conditions:
        - Field: host-header
          HostHeaderConfig:
            Values: !Ref DomainName
      Actions:
        - Type: redirect
          RedirectConfig:
            Protocol: HTTPS
            Port: 443
            Host: "#{host}"
            Path: "/#{path}"
            Query: "#{query}"
            StatusCode: HTTP_301
```

Interestingly a rule based upon the `Host` header even matches if I include an explicit port in the URL. Supposedly the `Host` header can include a port as well, so I don't know if A) AWS is ignoring the port when it does the comparison for `host-header`, or B) if the browser is stripping out the port if the default port is used. If the latter, then this could prevent access even to the correct domain if a browser decided to send the port in the `Host` header value. Hopefully AWS is parsing out the host part and only comparing that.